# How to store,retrieve and delete data using Ember Data?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, offline

am a newbie working with emberJs.

Currently, am developing an ember app that has reached a stage to implement the offline feature where previous data stored has to be accessed while offline.

In my app following code is of one of the templates I use, templates/bbc.hbs:

```
{{#link-to 'bbc'}}<img src="/assets/images/bbc-news-icon.png" alt="bbc news logo" style="max-width: 150px;min-height:150px;">{{/link-to}} 
{{log model}}

{{#each model.articles as |item|}}
<hr>
<div class="panel panel-primary">
<div class="panel-heading"><span class="badge">Title</span>
<h3>{{item.title}}</h3></div>
<div class="panel-body">
<span class="badge">Description</span>
{{item.description}}
</div>
<div class="panel-footer"><span class="badge">URL to News</span>
 <a href={{item.url}} target="_blank" role="link" aria-label={{item.title}}>   {{item.title}} </a>
 </div>
</div>

{{/each}}
{{outlet}}
```

and for the above template following is the corresponding route js file, routes/bbc.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
model(){
    return Ember.$.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=c4ea221e6833496bad7716c6c4fc5ece');
}
});
```

what I need to know is:

1)how to implement the ember data feature so that I could fetch the JSON data while online through this url and store it in a data-store.

2)Retrieve data from data-store to the route js file when the user moves to this route while online/offline.

3)Delete all previous data for that route if selected again while online and update new data received through the Url that receives JSON data. And if Offline just skip this step.

I have already implemented the service-worker with broccoli-serviceworker in this app to implement the offline feature.

Since I didn't find any way to store the data that could be accessed while offline like using IndexedDB feature I think ember data could help.

while asked for a review to my reviewer, he personally suggested me to use Ember Data with the broccoli-serviceworker package to configure a service worker that has access to Embers Data library.

if there is a better option regarding storing and retrieval of data that too with offline compatibility, its welcome.

Please do give a solution with step by step instructions that has to be followed to solve this issue

Github repo link to my project: https://github.com/JEEVANJGA/Capstone-News-App

Comment: I'm unsure if I understand - you want user to be able to pull data from the internet while offline (2nd point)? Ember app exists only user side. To be able to display some data it needs to download it to user browser first. The only case when your point 2 would work would be when user 1. opens the Ember app, sees list of things 2. disconnects internet 3. still can see the list of things, navigate through the app etc. while offline. Is that the thing you want to implement?

Comment: @Senthe yes. That's what I meant.
The App should display the data that it had while it was online before it went offline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your Ember.$.get with RSVP.Promise and use localStorage for caching:

1. Try to get feed
2. If request is successful, save data to local storage and resolve promise
3. If request failed, that's mean no internet, retrieve data from local storage and resolve promise. Optional: set timeout to refresh model in a minute.

With respect to the above instructions given by @Gennady Dogaev, @JEEVAN GEORGE ANTONY changed the routes/bbc.js file in the question as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({
model(){
function getJSON(url){
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.open('GET', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
    xhr.responseType = 'json';
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Accept', 'application/json');
    xhr.send();
    function handler() {
      if (this.readyState === this.DONE) {
        if (this.status === 200) {
          resolve(this.response);
        } else {
                  reject(new Error('getJSON: `' + url + '` failed with   status: [' + this.status + ']'));
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
 return getJSON('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=bbc-news&sortBy=top&apiKey=c4ea221e6833496bad7716c6c4fc5ece').then(function(json) {
      // on fulfillment
       var data = JSON.stringify(json);
         localStorage.setItem('bbcnews', data);
         return JSON.parse(data);
    }, function(reason) {
       // on rejection
              console.log(reason);
              var data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('bbcnews'));
              console.log(data);
             return data;
    });
  }
  });
```

This solves the offline accessiblity of data with ember using localstorage even without using ember data, pouchDB or indexedDB features.

Comment: Does the local storage data get lost if the session is over?
And if so, this solution wont be effective, right??

Comment: @JEEVANGEORGEANTONY local storage is permanent, you can learn about it at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage). Downsides of it are limited space (you can count on ~5MB) and speed. But there is no alternative client-side storage anyway. Web SQL Database, unfortunately, supported only by Chrome.

Comment: What about IndexedDB and PouchDB

Comment: For your solution can you give a detailed code snippet with comments

Comment: @JEEVANGEORGEANTONY I didn't work with IndexedDB, probably it's good, probably not. Browser support of pure Indexeddb is not good: for example, IE only 10+ and no Safari support

Comment: @JEEVANGEORGEANTONY Your code is good, but I see that you have few similar routes with similar code. You may improve your app, if you'll try to create a [service](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.11.0/applications/services/). For example, you may have a service called `news` with one method `load`. And in each model you will need just to inject it and call `return this.get('news').load('bbc-news');`. This will reduce amount of similar code and make changes easier (if you will need to change apiKey or move to other API for example).